# Orthogonal embeddings

Tags: neural-networks

I am looking to develop a neural network in which the output from one set of nodes is "orthogonal" to the output from another set of nodes in the sense that if the first set of nodes is used to predict A then the second set of nodes is uninformative of A. For example:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

# Define the size of the input
input_size = 10  # Replace this with the size of your input

# Input layer
inputs = Input(shape=(input_size,))

# Dense layer
dense = Dense(8, activation='relu')(inputs)

# Split the dense layer into two halves
dense1, dense2 = Lambda(lambda x: split(x, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1))(dense)

# Classification layers
output1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense1)
output2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense2)

# Create the model
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[output1, output2])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Print the model summary
model.summary()
```

I am looking for a way to ensure that `dense1` is uninformative of `output2` and `dense2` is uninformative of `output1`.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: i think that's a pretty interesting problem. the only thing I can think of is somewhat unstable and would have to be carefully optimized: to take inspiration from the GAN literature and to add two "discriminator" networks which accept the output of one of your models as input and try to predict the other's output. You would add the negative accuracy of these discriminators to each of your primary neural networks, GAN-style. We'd have to think about how to balance this new cost with the standard crossentropy loss. alternatively we could view this as a constraint to add to your problem.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Thanks! Let me try that and see what I get!

Comment: The GAN approach was indeed unstable. I ended up implementing https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume16/qiu15a/qiu15a.pdf. The results are much better. The intuition is to use the dot product between vectors in the two spaces to compute distance between the spaces. See equation 5.

Comment: What is exactly orthogonal output? In the binary classification case should I get a contingency table like: $$\begin{array}{c|cc}&output1 = a&output1 = b\\\hline output2=a&p_{1a}p_{2a}&p_{1b}p_{2a}\\output2 =b&p_{1a}p_{2b}&p_{1b}p_{2b}\end{array}$$ ie output that follows an independency relation $P(\text{output1 $=x$ and output2 $=y$}) = P(\text{output1} =x) \times P(\text{output2} =y)$

Comment: Yep. What I really want (and mean) is $P(output1 | dense1, dense2) =  P(output1 | dense1)$ and $P(output2 | dense1, dense2) =  P(output2 | dense2)$. Strictly speaking $dense1$ is not orthogonal to $dense2$, which is why I had it in quotes. Instead, $dense1$ is uninformative of $dense2$. One way to construct this is to force the vector spaces spanned by $dense1$ and $dense2$ to be "maximally separated" in a norm. If you use the nuclear norm then that translates out to equation 5. Maximally separated $\neq$ uninformative/orthogonal but I can't seem to find a better way to enforce uninformative.

Comment: What I really want is that the classifier probability is orthogonal and not that the embedding is orthogonal, so maybe mutually uninformative embeddings is a better term?

Comment: @AnirbanMukherjee what are output1, output2, dense1 and dense2 in the expressions of your last comments? Are dense1 and dense2 the 2x4 continuous outputs from the ReLu layer and are output1 and output2 the 2x1 binary outputs of the sigmoid activation layer?

Comment: If you look at the code, dense1 and dense2 are the splits of dense. output1 and output2 are the two classifiers connected to dense1 and dense2 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible solutions to this issue.

1. The use of GANs, as always, comes with the caveat that the model is difficult to train. In my application, each of the two classes has many labels. This was a deterrent to the use of discriminators.
2. I considered the use of the loss identified in Supervised Contrastive Learning (https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.11362). The issue here is that we need many labels of each type of class to be orthogonal to each other. The adoption of this loss function was a part of the final solution but proved to be insufficient in of itself.
3. I used the results in https://jmlr.org/papers/volume16/qiu15a/qiu15a.pdf. The addition to the loss function uses the dot product (similar to Supervised Constrastive Learning) but with a min and no logit-like formulation.

The combination of 2 and 3 proved sufficient in my application. They did lead to a need to use higher dimensionality subspaces, likely because the subspaces are forced to be orthogonal, but was an easy compromise to make in my data.

Comment: This talk gives an excellent overview of the key concepts. http://helper.ipam.ucla.edu/publications/glws1/glws1_15465.pdf